# Querying Deep JSONb Information - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following JSON array stored on a row:

```
{
    "openings": [
         {
             "visibleFormData": {
                 "productName": "test"
             }
         }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of `productName`. So far I've tried something like this:

`SELECT tbl.column->'openings'->'0'->'visibleFormData'->>'productName'`

The theory being that this would grab the first object (index 0) in the `openings` array and then grab the `productName` attribute from that object's `visibleFormData` object.

All I'm getting is null, though. I've tried multiple configurations of this. I'm thinking it has to do with the grabbing of index zero, but I am unsure. I am not a regular PSQL user, so it's proving a tad tricky to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json array index is `integer`, so use `0` instead of `'0'`:

```
with tbl(col) as (
values
    ('{
        "openings": [
             {
                 "visibleFormData": {
                     "productName": "test"
                 }
             }
        ]
    }'::jsonb)
)

SELECT tbl.col->'openings'->0->'visibleFormData'->>'productName'
FROM tbl

 ?column? 
----------
 test
(1 row)
```